# In chromium, how to combine --register-pepper-plugins with --launch-and-load-app

Tags: google-chrome, ppapi

I am using [chromium command line switch](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) `--launch-and-load-app` to start a chromium instance that shows only the app that I am developing. This is working well.

Also, I am using [`--register-pepper-plugins` to specify a shared library containing a PPAPI plugin](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/pepper-plugin-implementation). This too works well, so long as `--launch-and-load-app` is not specified.

Unfortunately, when the two are combined, instead of the plugin being loaded, only a box appears saying "`right-click to play my-plugin.so`". Right-clicking does not bring up an option to load the plugin.

How can I cause the plugin to play when using `--launch-and-load-app`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a temporary directory to act as chromium's user data directory.
2. Launch `chromium` specifying `--user-data-dir=<the temp directory>`, as well as the appropriate `--register-pepper-plugins` switch.
3. Visit a page containing an `<embed>` that loads your plugin.
4. Visit `chrome://plugins`. Find your plugin, and select '`Always allowed to run`"
5. Save a snapshot of the temporary user data directory; it can be used as the data directory to start an instance of `chromium` in which your plugin will run.